# SQL Update field in db from double lookup on another db

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a weight column in my new db with values from my old db.
(mssqlserver 2008).

new db part table columns: weight, partID

old db part table columns: partKey, partID

old db uom table columns: partKey, weight

To get weight for part in the old db you have to lookup the weight using partKey which you have to lookup in old db part table using partID

I've googled many answers but only thing I found were single lookups not double lookups?

Please help, I dont know sql at all but it must be done in sql. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply combine you old DB info with a join and then update against it.

```
update NewDB.Parts
set weight = OLD.weight
from NewDB.Parts 
join (select weight, partID
from oldDB.Parts p
    join oldDB.UOM on UOM.partKey = p.PartKey) as OLD on OLD.PartID=Parts.PartID
```